# get data to viewPager fragment from its fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, android-viewpager

I am using `viewPager` for my custom `Tablayout`.  I have two `fragments`, when `viewPager` activity was created , it should get the data from one of the fragment and have to display it on the tabs as unread count. 
but I am getting data at scrolling. how can I over come this issue ?. please help me.
[image]

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                PendingPlusPendingForUploadFiles frage = new PendingPlusPendingForUploadFiles();
                System.out.println("====c value===" + frage.count);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //  previousTabPosition = position;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you getting data at scrolling? Your PendingPlusPendingForUploadFiles doesn't seem to depend on anything, you can use it wherever you want

Comment: @elmorabea I am able to get the data . but it was displaying on tabs as unread count at the time of on Scrolling.

Comment: Where do you want to use "frage.count"?

Comment: like whats app unread count

Answer (score 0):

you can  onResume(); method in the Fragment get it!

Comment: Do you mean to get data when fragment are visible?

Comment: Do you want to get data at fragment when Activity is created?

Comment: yes, have to get the data  from fragment to that viewpager activity

Comment: onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState); method  in the Fragment

Comment: I am sorry!I do not know what do you want to do?

Comment: in the Activity ,you can judge viewPager Selected position ! if(0){you can set second tab unredcount }else{ you can set first tab unread count}

Comment: Hi, Please read my question. I am getting that count when scrolled viewpager. I want that count when activity was created.